# How can I drag a layer from a Document to Another?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I'm using `Adobe Illustrator CS6`.
I've two documents opened, A and B.

On B, I've 10 (main) layers. Each of them contains other N elements.
I'd like to drag and place one of these main layer to document A.

How can I do it? Tried to click, drag above document A, wait for document switch, and release over Layer panel on Doument A, but nothing happens.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, AI has not this as a native feature.

The trick is from the **Layers Panel Options** > Check **Paste Remembers Layers**

The layer to be copied must have a different name than any other layer at the next file.

Select all the layer items clicking at the **Layer Target Icon**:

[image: target]

**Copy** and **Paste** at the next file.